# How do I programmatically implement super user privileges in a script?

Tags: python, permissions

I've written a python script. One of the functions opens a port to listen on.  To open a port to listen on I need to do it as super user.  I don't want to run the script with `sudo` or with root permissions, etc.  I saw an answer here regarding sub-process using `sudo`.  It's not a sub-process I want as far as I know. It's just a function within the application.

Question: How do I programmatically open a port with super user permissions?

Comment: Can you share the code you've written relevant to this problem?

Comment: Can you not use a tool such as [authbind](https://manned.org/authbind.1) so you just grant to the python process that specific privilege...?

Comment: Take a look at capabilities instead: https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities. You may set capabilities, such as CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE for your script, then it should be able to bind to any ports without requiring root access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. If you could then malicious code would have free access to any system as root at any time!

If you want super user privileges you need to run the script from the root account or use sudo and type in the password - this is the whole point of having user accounts.

EDIT

It is worth noting that you can run bash commands from within a python script - for example using the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['sudo', 'blah'])
```

This essentially creates a new bash process to run the given command.

If you do this your user will be prompted to enter their password in the same way as you would expect, and the privileges will only apply to the subprocess that is being created - not to the script that you are calling it from (which may have been the original question).

Answer (score 0):

You could use sudo inside your python script like this, so you don't have to run the script with sudo or as root.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sudo", "cat", "/etc/shadow"])
```

Comment: sure but this is a workaround to the same thing right? The user still has to type in their password ...

Comment: The orginial question doesn't say anything about not entering a password. Obviously you're going to have to do that regardless.

Comment: Getting su privilege without typing password? No.

Comment: If I understood correct subprocess requires typing in the password?  That would work for me.

Comment: @user6035379 The permissions would apply to the other process though and not the Python process - so this just equates to running `sudo` within Python instead of just using `sudo` anyway...